# Sirikit - handler not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, siri, sirikit

I am currently adding SiriKit in my application and I have created an INExtension class. In my Info.plist I have the following code as below.

But each time I try to run the Intent Extension class on my device, none of the override handle methods are called by Siri. I have added logs in each methods but to no success. Is there anything else I am missing ?

Also FYI before posting this I referred the link but there were no answers: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323035/ios-sirikit-handler-not-called)

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked</key>
        <array>
            <string>INSearchForAccountsIntent</string>
        </array>
        <key>IntentsSupported</key>
        <array>
            <string>INSearchForAccountsIntent</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.intents-service</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).IntentHandler</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: So I figured out the issue which was that certain new Intents in Siri works only on iOS 11 and above devices and I was testing on iOS 10 devices.

Answer (score 4):

I faced similar problem - handler wasn't called.
Finally I've found out, that although the project supports iOS 11.4, it initially set IntentExtension target to iOS 13. And my device, which I use for testing, has 12.4.

So my advice: **check your deployment target for each target.**

Comment: OMG, I have been beating my head against the desk for weeks because my IntentHandler never got called on my test iOS 12 device.  I found out my Intent and IntentUI targets' build settings were incorrectly configured to target iOS 14.3 which caused the problem.  Changing them to target iOS 12.0 immediately resolved the issue.